# PHP Mysqli Can i get corrupted data by simultaneously load

Tags: php

i have a question, if 100 users load the page simultaneously and i have the script like this:

```
select(some data)
if(exist)
{ update the data / etc }
```

and another page script like this:

`delete(the data above)`

Can something like this happen?

```
select(some data)
if(exist) // we get that exist
{
   // and here the date will be deleted by page 2 and cannot update or will be corrupted data
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Multiple users running single queries at the same time will not conflict as single queries are run in isolation. If they need to run a _series_ of queries in isolation, then you need to use a transaction. Refer to your database's docs on how to use transactions.

Comment: Yes, what you are describing is possible

Comment: @Dharman and how can i fix the problem?

Comment: Lock the row before editing.